# Filepaths being saved as Temp path on server instead of original client name

Tags: laravel

I am having an extremely difficult time trying to get the proper filename to show up in my directory.  I am using putFileAs to save a file to a given folder.  That file location is saved in my database as C:\xampp\tmp\phpC652.tmp rather than the actual filename (i.e. Test.pdf).  Therefore, I cannot create a link to access this file in the view.

From Controller:

```
             case 'next_step':
            // Next Step Model
            $data = request()->validate ([  
                'current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1' => 'sometimes|file|max:5000',
                'current_plan_year_claims_data_file_2' => '',
                'current_plan_year_claims_data_file_3' => '',

            $plansubmission = PlanSubmission::find($id);
            $plansubmission->update($data);


                $files = array();
            $files[] = $request->file('current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
            $files[] = $request->file('prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
            $files[] = $request->file('2_years_prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');

           $files = $request->allFiles();
                            $folder = $id;
            if (count($files) > 0) {
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    //if files should be stored in public drive, change 'local' to 'public'
                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($folder, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
                    $plansubmission-> prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 = $filename;
                    $plansubmission->save();

                    ;
                }
```

Comment: *That file location is saved in my database as C:\xampp\tmp\phpC652.tmp* Can you show us the relevant code where you store the file in the database?

Comment: Maybe that is the problem.  I'm not sure I understand that part.  I have this in my view to display:           <a class='col-6' href="/download/{{ $plansubmission->id }}/{{$plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 }}">{{ $plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 }}</a> 
.   Then this in my web.php:  Route::get('/download/{folder}/{filename}', 'DownloadsController@getDownload');.  Then this in my DownloadsController: public function getDownload($folder, $filename){$pathToFile = storage_path('app/'.$folder.'/'.$filename);return response()->file($pathToFile);

Comment: I think you wanted this part:

                $plansubmission = PlanSubmission::find($id);
                $plansubmission->update($data);

Comment: No, where do you **save** `C:\xampp\tmp\phpC652.tmp` **in** your database after the upload. Something like `PlanSubmission::create([ ... ])` I guess

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show the full code when you store / update `$plansubmission` ?

Comment: I guess I don't know how to do that.  I thought it would store as the original file name.  I am validating the data from the form, then requesting all the files into the $files array variable, then storing those files in the filesystem, then running:

                $plansubmission = PlanSubmission::find($id);
                $plansubmission->update($data);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204223/discussion-between-alexander-and-cbaconnier).

Comment: you are saving the path of the uploaded file to the database (the temporary file), not the path to where you saved the file to

Comment: Thanks, I think I nearly have it but cannot figure out the 2nd to last line of code:

                    $plansubmission-> prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 = $filename;

I have to make the prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 a dynamic field that brings in the name of the column for the given item in the array